# How to put a hyperlink in the label of a dash Checkbox

Tags: python, plotly-dash

How can I have the label of a `dcc.Checkbox` be a hyperlink?

Imagine taking the first example [here](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/checklist)
and having "New York City", "Montreal", etc. each be a hyperlink.

Neither setting the label to be `'''<a href="...">text</a>'''` nor setting it to be a `html.A` object works.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with some javascript:

```
const labelUrls = [
  "https://www.google.com/search?q=New+York+City",
  "https://www.google.com/search?q=Montr%C3%A9al",
  "https://www.google.com/search?q=San+Francisco",
];

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  const labels = document.querySelectorAll("label");
  labels.forEach((label, index) => {
    const previousLabel = label.innerHTML;
    const previousLabelText = label.innerText;

    label.innerHTML = previousLabel.replace(
      previousLabelText,
      `<a href=${labelUrls[index]}>${label.innerText}</a>`
    );
  });
});
```

So the idea above is to create a list of urls that you want to navigate to, where each url corresponds to an option label in the checklist. Make sure the order of the urls corresponds to the order of the options in your `Checklist` component.

When the page has loaded we look for all labels. We use `innerHTML` to get the full label html as a string. We use `innerText` to get the text inside the label (input excluded). Then we set the new label to the old label `innerHTML`, but where the old label's `textContent` is replaced with an anchor tag.

I've passed `label` to `querySelectorAll` in this example, but in a page with more elements its probably a better idea to give the `Checklist` an `id` or `className` and target the labels using the `Checklist`'s identifier.

*For how to include Javascript in dash apps, see [this](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources).*

But the basic flow is to create an `assets` folder in the root directory and to put a javascript file inside with the code.